# When I use the Labeled command my graphics shrink

Tags: graphics, labeling

My first post regarding this matter was not well formulated so hopefully I have done a better job of reformulated my question here. The following code works well as far as it goes.

```
Manipulate[If[run == 20, run = 0];

 Module[
  {k1 = 0.2, k2 = 0.4, w = 1.3, A = 0.05, c = 0.01, L = 6},

  M[x_, y_, L_] := 
   Piecewise[{{0, y - L Sin[x] < 0}, {1, y - L Sin[x] > 0}}]*(y - 
      L Sin[x]);
  P[x_, y_, L_] := 
   Piecewise[{{0, y + L Sin[x] < 0}, {1, y + L Sin[x] > 0}}]*(y + 
      L Sin[x]);

  sys = {x''[t] + c x'[t] - 
      k1 Cos[x[t]] (M[x[t], y[t], 6] - P[x[t], y[t], 6]) == A Sin[w t],
    y''[t] + c y'[t] + k2 (M[x[t], y[t], 6] + P[x[t], y[t], 6]) == 
     9.8};

  ic = {x[0] == x0, x'[0] == xp0, y[0] == y0, y'[0] == yp0};
  sol = NDSolve[{sys, ic}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}]];

 {x1[t_], y1[t_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. Flatten[sol];
 l = 2 + 0.10 y1[run];
 p = 0;
 q = 1.8;

 GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[{Line[{{-5.5, -0.6}, {5.5, -0.6}}], 
      Line[{{-5, 3.8}, {-5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 - 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}], 
      Line[{{5, 3.8}, {5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 + 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}], Brown,
       Thickness[0.02], 
      Line[{{p - 5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 - 5*Sin[x1[run]])}, {p + 5, 
         q - (.9 l + 0.6 + 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}]},
     PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4, 6}}]}}, ImageSize -> {800, 600}],

 {{x0, 0, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(0\)]\)"}, -\[Pi]/
   6, \[Pi]/6, 0.001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{xp0, 0, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(.\)], \
\(0\)]\)"}, -1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{y0, 27.25, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(0\)]\)"}, -30, 30, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{yp0, 0, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(y\), \(.\)], \(0\)]\)"}, -10, 
  10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{run, 0, 
   Text[Style["release system", FontSize -> 18]]}, 0, 20, .01, 
  ControlType -> Trigger, AnimationRate -> 1}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> True, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, TrackedSymbols -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> 
  Style["Vertical and transverse motion of the Tacoma Narrows Bridge \
roadway", 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]]
```

Here is an image the code produces:[image: full size graphic]

I want to place a label to the immediate right of the horizontal bar generated by the above code. To do this I have wrapped the Labeled command around GraphicsGrid above with the code block below:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{Labeled[
    Graphics[{Line[{{-5.5, -0.6}, {5.5, -0.6}}], 
      Line[{{-5, 3.8}, {-5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 - 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}], 
      Line[{{5, 3.8}, {5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 + 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}], Brown,
       Thickness[0.02], 
      Line[{{p - 5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 - 5*Sin[x1[run]])}, {p + 5, 
         q - (.9 l + 0.6 + 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}]},
     PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4, 6}}], Text["Equilibrium"], Right, 
    LabelStyle -> Red]}}, ImageSize -> {800, 600}]
```

I have included the resulting image of the now shrunken graphic. How can I keep the graphic full size? [image: shrunken graphic with label]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
Manipulate[If[run == 20, run = 0];
 Module[{k1 = 0.2, k2 = 0.4, w = 1.3, A = 0.05, c = 0.01, L = 6}, 
  M[x_, y_, L_] :=  Piecewise[{{0, y - L Sin[x] < 0}, {1, y - L Sin[x] > 0}}]*(y - L Sin[x]);
  P[x_, y_, L_] :=  Piecewise[{{0, y + L Sin[x] < 0}, {1, y + L Sin[x] > 0}}]*(y + L Sin[x]);
  sys = {x''[t] + c x'[t] - k1 Cos[x[t]] (M[x[t], y[t], 6] - P[x[t], y[t], 6]) ==  A Sin[w t],  
         y''[t] + c y'[t] + k2 (M[x[t], y[t], 6] + P[x[t], y[t], 6]) ==  9.8};
  ic = {x[0] == x0, x'[0] == xp0, y[0] == y0, y'[0] == yp0};
  sol = NDSolve[{sys, ic}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}]];
 {x1[t_], y1[t_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. Flatten[sol];
 l = 2 + 0.10 y1[run];
 p = 0;
 q = 1.8;
 Labeled[Graphics[{Line[{{-5.5, -0.6}, {5.5, -0.6}}], 
    Line[{{-5, 3.8}, {-5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 - 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}], 
    Line[{{5, 3.8}, {5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 + 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}], Brown,   Thickness[0.02], 
    Line[{{p - 5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 - 5*Sin[x1[run]])}, {p + 5, 
           q - (.9 l + 0.6 + 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-4, 6}}, ImageSize -> {400, 300}], 
  Text["Equilibrium"], Right, 
  LabelStyle -> Red], {{x0, 0, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(0\)]\)"}, -π/6, π/6, 
  0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{xp0, 0, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(θ\), \(.\)], \
\(0\)]\)"}, -1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{y0, 27.25, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(0\)]\)"}, -30, 30, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{yp0, 0, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(y\), \(.\)], \(0\)]\)"}, -10, 
  10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{run, 0, 
   Text[Style["release system", FontSize -> 18]]}, 0, 20, .01, 
  ControlType -> Trigger, AnimationRate -> 1}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> True, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, TrackedSymbols -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> Style["Vertical and transverse motion of the Tacoma Narrows Bridge roadway", 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But personally, I would remove the Labeled[] thing and use just a Text inside Graphics:

```
Graphics[{
  Line[{{-5.5, -0.6}, {5.5, -0.6}}], , 
  Text[Style["Equilibrium", Medium, Bold, Red], {7, -.6}],
  Line[{{-5, 3.8}, {-5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 - 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}],
  Line[{{5, 3.8}, {5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 + 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}],
  Brown, Thickness[0.02], 
  Line[{{p - 5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 - 5*Sin[x1[run]])},
    {p + 5, q - (.9 l + 0.6 + 5*Sin[x1[run]])}}]},
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 10}, {-4, 6}}, ImageSize -> {400, 300}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks: GraphicsGrid caused my problem. I used GraphicsGrid because I have plots to include below the graphic. Can you make suggestions?

Comment: @Stephen See edit, please

Comment: Good idea. I am overwhelmed with all the graphics options and their constraints. Thanks so much

Comment: @Stephen Yes, it's the price for flexibility. There are too many different parameters and options, and it requires some practice to get through it.